# Does play framework 2.x support websocket timeout?

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.0, timeout

How can i set timeout for websockets in play framework 2.x? I can't find anything in play websocket API. I want to close websocket after some idle time?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Happening with me as well..

Answer (score 1):

I think the default time in play framework is 300 seconds, you have to ping time to time to keep the connection alive. Play framework doesn't have any configuration for websocket timeout.

With the above solution you can easily close you connection after certain timeperiod( as per your own configurtion)